# Regular Expression: Common string validation

Tags: python, regex

I am doing some basic validation. The flow of the program goes like:

- User inputs a string
- Clicks SUBMIT

Now I want to make sure the following rules are fulfilled:

- No spaces
- Must be alphanumeric... no special charatcers! (ie !@#$%^&*)
- Must start with a letter
- Must be at least 3 characters

How can I do this using python/django regular expressions?

Please Help

Comment: did you mean "Must be at least 3 digits" or "Must be at least 3 characters"?

Comment: at least 3 characters (e.g. xxx is valid)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
re.compile("^[A-Za-z]\w{2,}$")

>>> re.compile("^[A-Za-z]\w{2,}$")
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x0272C158>
>>> expr=re.compile("^[A-Za-z]\w{2,}$")
>>> expr.match("A12345")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02721288>
>>> expr.match("A1")
>>> expr.match("1AS")
>>> expr.match("AB1")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0272E138>
>>> expr.match("ab1")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02721288>
>>> expr.match("Abhijit$%^&#@")
>>>
```

Comment: this does not handle the case for special characters

Comment: example "Abhijit@#%" is true. As point 2 says no special characters except for dash ('-') and underscore ('_')

Comment: Sry about that. Just add a $ at the end like
re.compile("^[A-Za-z]\w{2,}$")

Comment: I have modified my post accordingly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5679/discussion-between-abhijit-and-mangobug)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this in Python without regular expressions:

```
if a.isalnum() and a[0].isalpha() and len(filter(str.isdigit, a)) >= 3:
    ...
```

If according to @Toomai "3 digits" are "at least 3 characters long", then this is what you need:

```
if a.isalnum() and a[0].isalpha() and len(a) >= 3:
    ...
```

Comment: If the question means "at least 3 characters long" and not "includes at least 3 numbers", then you can get rid of the filter.

Comment: @Toomai - added the other alternative too.

Comment: @eumiro: what if we have to include '-' and '_' (dash and underscore) to the list, wont a.isalnum() be a hassle?